# Nodejs new url.URL("https://myurl.com:80") lists the port as empty

Tags: node.js, url, port

I've noticed that if I use `url` to parse a string

```
const url = require('url');
const myUrl = new url.URL("http://myurl.com:80")
```

The resulting object will list `myUrl.port` as "". However if I instead set

```
const url = require('url');
const myUrl = new url.URL("http://myurl.com:70")
```

it'll list `myUrl.port` as "70".

I understand that port 80 is a default. But why does the module go to the trouble of stripping the port I've explicitly set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's how the URL module is designed for Node JS . As per the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_port)

> The port value may be a number or a string containing a number in the
>   range 0 to 65535 (inclusive). Setting the value to the default port of
>   the URL objects given protocol will result in the port value becoming
>   the empty string ('').

So if you use `80 (http)` it will give the empty string for the port.
And if you  have `https` url something like `https://myurl.com:443` the default port will be empty string too.

There is a noteworthy thing here that protocol you are assigning to your request must match with the default port it takes .Like if you have url like

```
https://myurl.com:80
```

Then it will return port as `80` ,and not empty string as default port for `https` is `443`

Comment: Better yet, this is mentioned in the [URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#port-state): "Set url’s port to null, if port is url’s scheme’s default port, and to port otherwise."

Comment: Yes ,you are right ,but the question is about what if we give default port ,then obviously it will be euqivalent to null and given empty string.